# How to center align text for background image for OUTLOOK in HTML Email Template?

Tags: html, outlook, background-image, html-email, vml

I am creating **Email Template**. Where I want and **background image** for `<td>`. I have used **VML** code to make it work on **Outlook and its older versions**. I have tested my **Email Template** and it is working fine in **Browser** and **GMAIL** but not working in **OUTLOOK**

> I want to achieve the result which is in below **screenshot**. Which I am getting in **Browser** and **GMAIL** but no in **OUTLOOK**

[image]

> In **Outlook** text **Your Quertly Update** is rendering on top left.
>   I have tried to use
>   **`position: absolute; top: 50%; left:0 right: 0;`**
>   but that is also not working

[image]

Here is the code below which I am using.

Code:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" height="100" align="center">
  <tr>


 <td background="https://picsum.photos/600/100" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="530" height="95" valign="middle" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/600/100');background-repeat:no-repeat; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
 
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:530px;height:95px;color:#ffffff">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://picsum.photos/600/100" color="#ffffff" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
 
   <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:40px; color:#ffffff; margin: 0;">Your quarterly Update</p>
  
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there anything which I need to change in **VML code** to get my text in 
 center and middle, **vertically and horizontally.**

Comment: Outlook does not support `position: absolute;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the contents of the paragraph and place it in a table with padding on the `td`. Below is the method I use:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" height="100" align="center">
  <tr>


 <td background="https://picsum.photos/600/100" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="530" height="95" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/600/100');background-repeat:no-repeat;vertical-align:top;">
 
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:530px;height:95px;color:#ffffff">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://picsum.photos/600/100" color="#ffffff" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" height="100" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:40px; color:#ffffff;text-align:center;padding-top:20px;">Your quarterly Update</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a 100% width div with align center as a wrap around your bg image element :

```
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<div align="center" style="text-align:center; width: 100%;">
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:530px;height:95px;color:#ffffff">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://picsum.photos/600/100" color="#ffffff" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->

   <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:40px; color:#ffffff; margin: 0;">Your quarterly Update</p>

  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
</div>
  <![endif]-->
```